# FindAddressCandidates API is given the location of the middle of the building , Is there any way to get gate location?

Tags: routes, maps, arcgis

FindAddressCandidates API is given the location of the middle of the building , Is there any way to get gate location ?

https://geocode-api.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/World/GeocodeServer/findAddressCandidates?address=37%20Dover%20Street%2C%20SUMMER%20HILL%2C%20NSW%2C%202130&f=json&token=

[image]